# Will a better CPU (or one with more cores) reduce Unity script compile time?

Tags: unity

It usually takes 10-15 seconds to compile for small changes in any of the scripts in my project. The project contains over hundred scripts, which are in C#.

Comment: By multiple CPU I meant server motherboard with multiple CPU. Thanks for the correction. :) (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster CPU speeds will result in faster compile times, yes.

Looking at Windows Task Manager when compiling, mono.exe maxes out only one of my CPU cores, so multiple cores probably won't help.

Comment: I see spikes on 5 out of 6 cores during compilation. But none of them goes max. And overall using 50-60% during compilation. Is it anyhow Unity's limitation? Or AMD cpu?

On a dual core it took 50-60 seconds and used ~100% CPU.

Comment: There's a limit to how much work it can split up and throw unto the CPU, it's not necessarily something you can't configure, but it's most likely just Unity's compiler/jit code.